# How to select second record after first from mysql base

Tags: php, mysql

```
1. p1 | cat   | mause
2. p2 | mause | cat
```

Hello,
I'd like to select 2 records form database with condition. My query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (p1 LIKE cat OR p2 LIKE cat) AND (p1 LIKE mause OR p2 LIKE mause)
```

ok this query will select 2 rows, it will select every row which contains "cat" and "mause" and this is a problem because I want to select only first row because first I select "cat" and next in p3 is "mause".

In the second row "mause" is at p1 column so this row shouldn't be selected because "cat" is after "mause".

__*_*__*_*__*_*_*SOME UPDATES TO MY QUESTION****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

Below is My example of table from database. All of records are definied as VARCHAR. I must write link because I have low reputation in stackoverflow and I can't pase image here.

[Link to image with database](http://z1.przeklej.pl/prze1932/7a67caae0027b4094ea65ee5/stationsdatabase.jpg)

I want to select the route from Las Vegas to Chicago. But when I do this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (station1 LIKE Las Vegas OR station2 LIKE Las Vegas OR station3 LIKE Las Vegas) AND (station1 LIKE Chicago OR station2 LIKE Chicago OR station3 LIKE Chicago)
```

it will select all of the rows which contains Las Vegas and Chicago, but I don't want to select the route where Chicago is first in the database. I only want to select this routes where Las Vegas is before Chicago in the table. So it will be only first row the "row 1".

In row 2 Las Vegas is after Chicago (Las Vegas station number 3, Chicago station 2) so I don't want to, the same at row 3.

I think it's now clear for everyone.

Comment: Can you explain better or add a larger example?

Comment: glad im not the only one confused here

Comment: Table def is the table definition, i.e. which fields are in your table and which type the are...

Comment: Can you explain what p1, p2 and p3 are? Which are your table fields? Show us records you have in your table and records you want to get from your query

Comment: I only want to select this routes where Las Vegas is before Chicago in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand what you mean, but I guess! Is this OK?:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable
    WHERE (station1 LIKE '%Las Vegas%' AND (
               station2 LIKE '%Chicago%' OR
               station3 LIKE '%Chicago%' OR
               station4 LIKE '%Chicago%' OR
               station5 LIKE '%Chicago%')
          ) OR
          (station2 LIKE '%Las Vegas%' AND (
               station3 LIKE '%Chicago%' OR
               station4 LIKE '%Chicago%' OR
               station5 LIKE '%Chicago%')
          ) OR
          (station3 LIKE '%Las Vegas%' AND (
               station4 LIKE '%Chicago%' OR
               station5 LIKE '%Chicago%')
          ) OR
          (station4 LIKE '%Las Vegas%' AND (
               station5 LIKE '%Chicago%')
          )
```

In order to generate such a `WHERE`clause, you can to something like:

```
$arr_sta = array('station1', 'station2', 'station3', 'station4');
$nbstations = count($arr_sta);
$where = '';
for($i=0; $i<$nbstations-1; $i++) {
    $where .= $where ? ' OR (' : ' WHERE (';
    $where .= $arr_sta[$i] . " LIKE '%Las Vegas%'";
    $where2 = '';
    for($j=$i+1; $j<$nbstations; $j++) {
        $where2 .= $where2 ? ' OR ' : ' AND (';
        $where2 .= $arr_sta[$j] . " LIKE '%Chicago%'";
    }
    if ($where2) $where .= $where2 . ')';
    $where .= ')';
}
```

Comment: No it is not OK.  I only want to select this routes where Las Vegas is before Chicago in the table. My original databse has about 100 000 rekords. This is only simple example.

Comment: @MarcinKostrzewa: What do you mean by `Las Vegas is before Chicago in the table`?

Comment: I mean that for example Las Vegas is in column number 1 and Chicago is in Column number 2 or 3 or 4 etc., or f.e. Las Vegas is in column 10 so Chicago must be further f.e in column number 13.

Comment: Yes that's correct:) But is there any shorter way? Because I have over 200 columns :/ so there will be a lot of code.:/

Comment: Looks like the solution to what he described. The query might get VERY huge if there are many columns (like 13 in his last comment). But the only other Solution i see is creating a temporary table with the positions of both cities you are looking for and then selecting from that.

Comment: OK! the query takes obut 3 seconds so will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding LIMIT 0, 1 to the end of your query.

Comment: It's hard to explain it but I try. I want to find only this possibility where the word cat is on the first place. (For example without animals:) When I want to select a route from Las Vegas to Chicago so I don't want to select a route from Chicago to Las Vegas too)

Comment: I make some updates in my question I think now it will be clear for everyone.